# Is there a simple way to mutate an enum field in Rust?

Tags: enums, rust, pattern-matching

Suppose we have an enum that looks like this:

```
enum MyEnum {
    Field1,
    Field2 {x: f64, y: f64},
    /* Maybe some other fields */
    MyString(String),
}
```

Now I created an instance of this enum of the subtype `MyString` and after some actions I want to mutate it. For example:

```
fn main() {
    let mut my_enum = MyEnum::MyString("Hello, world".to_string());
    /* Some actions */
    // Mutating the string
    match my_enum {
        MyEnum::MyString(ref mut content) => {
            content.push('!');
        },
        _ => {}
    }
    // Printing the string
    match my_enum {
        MyEnum::MyString(content) => {
            println!("{}", content);
        },
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

However, matching in such a way is pretty cumbersome when we know exactly from the context that `my_enum` can be **only** `MyString`. I would rather write something like this (not a correct Rust syntax):

```
my_enum@MyString.push('!');
println!("{}", my_enum@MyString);
```

And if, suppose, `my_enum` is of the subtype `Field2`, then to mutate `x`:

```
my_enum@Field2.x += 1.0;
```

Can I do something like this? I strongly suppose that the answer is "No", because if I remove `_ => {}` from the matches above, type checker starts complaining about non-exhaustive pattern matching:

```
patterns `Field1` and `Field2` not covered
```

though it can be inferred that `my_enum` can be nothing but `MyString`. By "inferred" I mean the compiler could track for all the variables of the type `MyEnum` what subtypes of values they can contain exactly.

I found a place in a larger code where this could be convenient, though I guess I can rewrite it in other way. However, I think that the compiler could be smarter and at least understand that in this context the pattern `MyEnum::MyString` is exhaustive. If the answer on the question above is really "No", as I suspect, I'm interested if this issue was discussed among Rust developers (maybe a RFCS link?) and if it is worth to make a feature request.

Comment: `if let MyEnum::MyString(ref mut content) = my_enum { content.push('!'); }`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of Rust 1.15.1, the compiler won't recognize that a particular variable can only be a particular variant of an `enum` at some point of execution. As such, you always need to write an exhaustive `match` on it.

However, some Rust developers [have been considering](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2015/08/20/virtual-structs-part-3-bringing-enums-and-structs-together/) making it such that each `enum` variant would be its own type, which would be a subtype of the `enum` itself.

If your variant has many data fields, or if you have methods attached to it, you could consider wrapping the `enum` variant's fields in a `struct` and use that `struct` directly, bypassing the enum entirely until you do need the enum for whatever reason. If you have only a few fields, and don't need to call methods on the enum, then you might be able to get away with just keeping a mutable pointer to each field that you obtain at the beginning with an exhaustive `match`, like this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut my_enum = MyEnum::MyString("Hello, world".to_string());
    let content = 
        match my_enum {
            MyEnum::MyString(ref mut content) => content,
            _ => unreachable!(),
        };

    /* Some actions */
    // Mutating the string
    content.push('!');

    // Printing the string
    println!("{}", content);
}
```

As of [Rust 1.26](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1260-2018-05-10), the explicit `ref` and `ref mut` keywords are no longer required.

Answer (score 10):

If you have an entire section of code in which the variable is known to have a particular type, you could just put that code inside the `match`, or if there's only one `match` arm which you care about, use `if let`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut my_enum = MyEnum::MyString("Hello, world".to_string());
    /* Some actions */
    if let MyEnum::MyString(ref mut content) = my_enum {
        content.push('!');
        //...
        println!("{}", content);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if it's just the verbose `match` (or `if let`) which is the problem, you can write methods to make it tidier:

```
impl MyEnum {
    fn push(&mut self, char c) {
        if let MyEnum::MyString(ref mut content) = *self {
            content.push(c);
        } else {
            unreachable!();
        }
    }

    // In practice print might be more generic, for example implement
    // Display
    fn print(&self) {
        if let MyEnum::MyString(ref content) = *self {
            println!("{}", content);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    //...
    my_enum.push('!');
    my_enum.print();
}
```

As of [Rust 1.26](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1260-2018-05-10), the explicit `ref` and `ref mut` keywords are no longer required.